# How to parametrize the volume of the intersection of cube and a right tetrahedron?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

This is an extension of [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/975924/why-can-i-not-combine-integrals-this-way).

I am trying to find the volume of the region which is the intersection of a cube given by $\vec r_1 = (x,y,z)$, where $$\begin{cases}0 \le x \le 1 \\ 0 \le y \le 1 \\ 0 \le z \le 1\end{cases}$$ and a right tetrahedron given by $\vec r_2 = (x,y,z)$, where $$\begin{cases}0 \le x \le 1-y-z \\ 0 \le y \le 1-z \\ 0 \le z \le 1\end{cases}$$

It seems like this region should be parametrizable as $\vec r = (x,y,z)$, where $$\begin{cases}1-y-z \le x \le 1 \\ 1-z \le y \le 1 \\ 0 \le z \le 1\end{cases}$$ However when computing the integral $\int^1_0 \int^1_{1-z} \int^1_{1-y-z} \text{dxdydz}$, I get $\frac 23$.  I know this must be wrong because the area of the cube is $1$ and the area of the right tetrahedron is $\frac 16$, thus I should be getting $\frac 56$.

Where is the flaw in my thinking?

Answer (score 0):

The tetrahedron is already given in a parametrized form:
$$\begin{cases}0 \le x \le 1-y-z \\ 0 \le y \le 1-z \\ 0 \le z \le 1\end{cases}$$
which is **not** equivalent to
$$\begin{cases}1-y-z \le x \le 1 \\ 1-z \le y \le 1 \\ 0 \le z \le 1\end{cases},$$
which is a prism whose volume is half of the cube.  The first restraint
$$\begin{cases}1-y-z \le x \le 1 \\ 1-z \le y \le 1 \\ 0 \le z \le 1\end{cases}$$
is weak and should be replaced by $0\le x\le1$, and for this incorrect region, your integral should instead be
$$\int^1_0 \int^1_{1-z} \int^1_{0} \text{dxdydz}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Try to draw both the correct and incorrect regions if you have trouble following the arguments above.

---

The correct triple integral is:
$$\int^1_0 \int^{1-z}_{0} \int^{1-y-z}_{0} \text{dxdydz}=\frac{1}{6}.$$